# How do I organize my activity layouts with the smallest possible layout folders?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-size

I have three layout files for an activity:

- `layout-small-ldpi`
- `layout-normal-mdpi`
- `layout` (for the rest)

When visiting the activity with a normal-hdpi mobile, Android pulled the layout from `normal-mdpi/`. Then I put the generic layout into a new configuration: `layout-normal-hdpi/` which seems to do the trick of pulling that layout for `sizes>=normal && density>=hdpi`. It also seems to pull the `normal-hdpi` layout with devices of `large-mdpi` configuration which is fine by me.

Will this solution cause me any troubles? Is there any better way for keeping the number of layout folders to a minimum of 3? I have read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) but it's nice to have a second opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to support as many screen sizes as possible with as little layouts as possible. Here is a good link to a PDF that should help you out.
[Scaling Android Apps with White Paper](http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Scaling_Android_Apps_White_Paper.pdf)